# Python function name convention for "convert foo to bar", e.g., foo_to_bar, foo2bar

Tags: python, naming, functions, naming-standards

I have a function that converts `args` given by `argparse` to a `filename`:

```py
def args2filename(args, prefix):
    filename = prefix
    kwargs = vars(args)
    for key, value in sorted(kwargs.items()):
        filename += f'_{key}={value}'
    return filename
```

What is the Python convention for such functions? I'd guess it would be more appropriate to use `args_to_filename` (or maybe `argstofilename` as in `2to3`) instead of `args2filename`, but I couldn't find a reference.

[I've found this answer for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962726/957997), but it addresses the case when you have a class. @lvc suggests `from_foo`, if `Bar.__init__` already takes a different signature:

```
 class Bar:
      @classmethod
      def from_foo(cls, f):
          '''Create a new Bar from the given Foo'''
          ret = cls()
          # ...
```

So, I'm looking for a Pythonic answer in these two cases, i.e., when I don't necessarily need a class, and when I have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) suggests using lowercase with underscores for function names. Incidentally, this style is also known as [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). Coincidence, or irony? :)

So if you wish to follow those conventions, then `args_to_filename` is a good choice. Of course, such guidelines are just that: a guide. As long as you are consistent with your own convention, then you are free to disregard "official" guidelines in favour of your own. Consistency is the key. Following a convention is just an easy way of achieving that consistency.

Regarding when to have a free function and when to have a method in a class, that's largely a matter of preference. The rule of thumb I use (for any language; not just Python) is:

Is the function "pure", ie is it deterministic (the same input arguments always yield the same result) and has no side effects (it doesn't read/write to external resources, eg global variables, environment variable or the file system)?
- If yes, make it a free function.
- If no, make it a method in a class

But others will have other criteria for deciding which option to pick.

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be better to use it in a generic form so you convert some args to a specific format. simply say `toYourFormat` in your case you can keep on saying `toFileName` but if you found a more generic name it can be better.

But anyway I think your design could be better if these `args` was instead a class that `toFileName` is a method of it and the class is responsible of collecting the args and converting them. *it's just a thought so it is not necessary the right one*